# Description of the 2-monads for (strict) monoidal categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monads, 2-categories

The nLab article on [2-monads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-monad#algebras_and_pseudoalgebras_over_a_2monad) says:

> For example, ordinary (non-strict) monoidal categories are the strict algebras for a strict 2-monad $T_{MC}$ on $Cat$, but usually we care about pseudo, lax, and oplax monoidal functors rather than strict ones. Strict monoidal categories are the strict algebras for a different strict 2-monad $T_{StrMC}$ on $Cat$.

Where can I get a description of such two 2-monads? I am confused by the strictness in $T_{MC}$ which produces non necessarily strict monoidal categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vague idea is that $TC$ is not the ordinary free monoidal category on $C$ made of strings in $C$, but instead is made of binary trees with leaves from $C$. This just means refining a string to remember the order of parentheses, and $TC$ has isomorphisms between the trees corresponding to different parenthesizations of the same string.

You can find some discussion of this stuff in Lack's 2-categories companion; abstractly, the idea is to take the "flexible" or "cofibrant" replacement of the monad $S$ for strict monoidal categories. Such a replacement $S'$ exists for any 2-monad, with the property that strict $S'$-algebras are equivalent to pseudo $S$-algebras. This is a theoretical justification for mostly ignoring pseudo algebras. An interesting remark special to this case is that $S$ is equivalent to $T$, which means their strict algebras are also equivalent. Composing, strict $S$-algebras are equivalent to pseudo ones, which is a fancy way of stating Maclane's theorem that every monoidal category can be strictified. This is emphatically *not* generalizable to arbitrary monads, as the failure of the coherence theorem for *symmetric* monoidal categories implies.

Comment: I am sorry, I got lost. The $T$ is a strict 2-monad whose strict algebras are monoidal categories, right? What is $S$? Is it a strict monad whose pseudo-algebras are strict monoidal categories? The 2-monad which is made of strings (without considering parenthesis) would be $S$ or $S'$? Is it strict or not?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear notation! All these 2-monads are strict. You're right about T. S has strict algebras the strict monoidal cats, so it's made of strings. S' is a general notation for the flexible replacement, and in our case we have S'=T.