# Construction of 2-category of monoidal categories and (lax) monoidal functors as strict algebra category of a 2-monad

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, monads, 2-categories

As motivation for 2-monads, I would like to understand an explicit construction of the 2-monad $T$ of which derived 2-category $T-\operatorname{Alg}_l$ of algebras as described in Lack's 2-categories companion produces the 2-category of monoidal categories, lax monoidal functors and lax natural transformations. I would like $T$ very explicitly specified in contrast to e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616089/description-of-the-2-monads-for-strict-monoidal-categories) which uses as starting point "free monoid construction" which makes sense to me only as functor $\operatorname{Set} \to \operatorname{Mon} \to \operatorname{Cat}$ instead as what Lack says being $\operatorname{Cat} \to \operatorname{Cat}$.

Comment: There's no mention of a "free monoid construction" at your link.

Comment: But in case it helps, there is a free monoid construction in many, many categories, including any category $C$ with finite products that distribute over countable coproducts. $\mathrm{Cat}$ is, of course, such a category, and there as in any such $C$ the free monoid on an object $x$ is defined as the object of strings from $x,$ that is, $\coprod_{n\in \mathbb N} x^n,$ with the multiplication operation  $(\coprod_n x^n)\times (\coprod_n x^m)\cong \coprod_{m,n} x^n\times x^m \to \coprod_n x^n$ having for its $m,n$th component the canonical isomorphism $x^n\times x^m\cong x^{n+m}.$

Comment: Thanks. The free monoid construction is what Lack mentions as being the 2-monad that creates 2-category of strict monoidal categories, of which the answer suggests taking replacement of. I would though like immediate construction $T$ of the 2-monad for (nonstrict) monoidal categories. The first paragraph of the mentioned answer describes how $T$ is supposed to map objects, but this is hardly enough for a 2-functor.

Comment: It’s likely a bit much to ask somebody to explicitly write down a 2-functor for you in every detail. For formal proofs, one works with the monad via its universal property, not a formula, so it’s not inconceivable that nobody has *ever* published this 2-functor completely explicitly. You can most likely write down the definition in however much detail you prefer from what you know already, and if not, you should ask a specific question.

Comment: Would you perhaps be able to recommend a text or few from which one is supposed to learn how to construct such 2-monads?

Comment: I’d always start with Lack and follow his references for more complete proofs as necessary. He gives the construction of this monad in terms of colimits as an explicit example.